# Next year, because something else "came out/will have come out", everyone will say it is not that good. - which one is correct?

Tags: meaning, tense, future-perfect

**Example 1**

> Everyone says the game is amazing now. Next year, because something else will **have come out**, everyone will say it is not that good.

**Example 2**

> Everyone says the game is amazing now. Next year, because something else **came out**, everyone will say it is not that good.

Is Example 2 correct?
I am not sure simple past can be used like this. I always feel we have to use future perfect to show different timings in the future.

Comment: Example 2 isn't idiomatic with ***because*** + Past Tense ***came out***. It could be fixed by changing ***because*** to ***if*** or ***when*** (but then you'd also have to change *everyone **will** say* to *everyone **would** say*). Personally, I don't like ***because*** here anyway, but from my point of view it would be *much* worse if you had ***if*** or ***when*** + Future Tense ***will.*** Whenever I see ***If** something **will** happen...*, I always assume it's from a non-native speaker. Native Anglophones say ***If** something **happens*** (or ***...does happen***).

Comment: Neither: *Everyone says the game is amazing now. Next year, when something else comes out, everyone will say it is not that good.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you. You say using "if or when" can fix it, but I don't remember unreal future conditional can take "when." Could you elaborate a little more? Thank you again.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "unreal future conditional". But in your context there's obviously a difference between using ***because*** or ***if*** to refer to a future situation. The former normally implies an *inevitable* future, but the latter (which is far more context-dependent) could refer to a possible future anywhere between almost certain to happen, and vanishingly unlikely to happen. We're more likely to refer to the "certain" future using Present Tense, and the "unlikely" future using Subjunctive, Past, or another "non-Present" verb form.